# printf in c printing extra charactors

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to stack overflow and c. Tell me if i need to add more details

I am trying to make a hangman game and when I try to print the board `draw_board()` Everything works except for printing the word on the board (should be `_ _ _ _` for the word free). It gives `_ _ _ _ jdgx` for the word free for example. There shouldn't be any extra letters. I have tried printing out the string itself not in the `draw_board()` function and it works fine out if `draw_board()` but it doesn't work in the function.

Code to generate string

```c
    const int Size = strlen(Word);

    printf("Your Word is: %s. With a len of %d.", Word, Size);

    char *Word_Letters = malloc(Size);

    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        *(Word_Letters + i) = '_';
    }
    *(Word_Letters+Size) = '\0';
```

Code to print board

```c
printf(" _____\n |   o\n |  %c|%c\n |  %c %c\n_|_\n\n%s\n\nEnter Guess: \0", LA, RA, LL, RL, LetterString);
```

The output i am getting is

```
Your Word is: bead. With a len of 4. 

_ _ _ _ AvSV

Enter Guess:
```

Here is a pastebin of the entire program https://pastebin.com/FC2LQZcm

Edit:
I changed `malloc(Size)` on line 85 with `malloc(Size+1)` and it did not work

2nd edit:
The problem was the string that got printed was made differently and wasn't null terminated. thanks @paddy for pointing out the problem.
Changed

```
23  char LetterString[LetterSize*2]; ->  char LetterString[LetterSize*2+1];
```

Added

```
LetterString[LetterSize*2] = '\0';
```

on line 35.

Comment: The following sentence is unclear: `"I have tried printing out the string itself out of draw_board() and it works fine online in draw_board() does it not work."` Please specify exactly what does work and what does **not** work. Also, simply stating that something does not work [is not a sufficient description of the problem](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). Please specify exactly in what way it does not work. For example, if the output is not what you want, please specify the desired output as well as the actual output.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste.

Comment: I add more info

Comment: You have the same problem with `LetterString`, which is not null-terminated.

Comment: @paddy That was the problem. If you post a answer i will check it as correct.

Comment: The correct answer is already posted by Vlad. Both of you simply didn't notice that there was a second unterminated string. But their answer is basically saying "make sure you have enough memory and terminate your strings", which is the primary thing you were not doing. You can just add a comment on it to say "whoops, I also needed to terminate LetterString", and then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You allocated memory for an array with `Size` elements

```
char *Word_Letters = malloc(Size);
```

The valid range of indices is `[0, Size)`.

So these statements

```
*(Word_Letters+Size) = '\0';
*(Word_Letters+Size+1) = 'N';`
```

invoke undefined behavior because there are attempts to write outside the allocated memory.

Note: these statements

```
*(Word_Letters+Size) = '\0';
*(Word_Letters+Size+1) = 'N';`
```

are equivalent to

```
Word_Letters[Size] = '\0';
Word_Letters[Size+1] = 'N';`
```

You should allocate memory .like

```
char *Word_Letters = malloc(Size + 2);
```

On the other hand, it seems this statement

```
*(Word_Letters+Size+1) = 'N';`
```

does not make sense because it sets an element of the array after the end of the stored string due to the preceding statement

```
*(Word_Letters+Size) = '\0';
```

Maybe actually you mean

```
*(Word_Letters+Size) = 'N';`
*(Word_Letters+Size + 1) = '\0';
```

Comment: I left setting the N char thing there by accident I used it for devugging

Comment: I remove that code from the post to clear up confusion

Comment: @CarsonCoder O'k but it is not very important.  The main problem is accessing memory outside the allocated array.